# Refilling cells without exceeding a certain amount, by a given percentage

Tags: worksheet-function, cells

I am sorry if this question might sound quite complicated, I will try to be the more clear possible.

I need that the amount in H13 (18,70€ in this case, if positive of course) refill the negative cells in H, without exceeding the negative amount (in this case it cannot be higher than 0,30 €, so the total should be 0 in H5), based on a given percentage (you will see it in the formula in C2).
The formula I put is as follow, `=IF(AND((H5<0); ($H$13>0));($H$13/100*C5); "-")` but I am struggling how to set the "refilling" thing without exceeding the 0,30€. I guess I have to add something like `ABS`.

This is the table I try to fix:
[image: This is how the cells look like]

Is someone able to help me with that? I'd very grateful! Thanks! Please don't hesitate to ask questions, I'll be happy to answer if you have doubts or questions!

Comment: How should your final result look, based on this example?

Comment: Hello ZydD,
the final result should be for all cells "-" but the one negative should show "0,30 €" as it is the amount it misses and it is below the given % set for that cell (reference in the formula at C5)
Thanks for your help!